# Pascal - Простой Paint на клавишах

Tags: pascal

Делаю простую рисовалку на Pascal.
Нужно сделать режим рисования(сделан), режим ластика (сделан), и режим просто перемещения кисти без рисования (не могу).
Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

```
uses graphabc,crt,events;

var x,y:integer;
    c:char;
    drawmode: string;

const WH = 600;
      WW = 600;
      color_px = clBlack;

procedure draw_px(col:integer);
begin
  SetPenColor(col);
  SetBrushColor(col);
  rectangle(x,y,x+10,y+10)
end;



procedure kDown(key: integer); { ????????? ????????? ??????? ?????? }
begin
  if drawmode = 'no' then draw_px(clWhite);
  if key=VK_Left then x:=x-10; { ????? }
  if key=VK_Right then x:=x+10; { ?????? }
  if key=VK_Up then y:=y-10; { ????? }
  if key=VK_Down then y:=y+10; { ???? }
  if key=VK_Escape then CloseWindow; { ??????? ???? }
  if key=VK_Space then
     begin
      if drawmode = 'yes' then
        drawmode:='no'
      else
        if drawmode = 'no' then
           drawmode:='yes';
    end;

  SetWindowCaption('x='+IntToStr(x)+' y='+IntToStr(y) + ' flag=' + drawmode);
  draw_px(clBlack);
end;


begin
  setWindowSize(WH,WW);
  x := WW div 2;
  y := WH div 2;
  drawmode:= 'yes';
  OnKeyDown:=kDown;

end.
```

Comment: Режим ластика мой изначально задумывался как режим передвижения, но так и не смог понять, как сделать, чтобы он не закрашивал белым уже покрашенное.

Comment: Ну это же... точно так же, как рисование, только без рисования.

Comment: Для начала, наверное, стоит сделать три режима?

Comment: Какие именно? не понимаю вас

Comment: Как? 
точно так же, как рисование, только без рисования
Без рисования - значит рисовать цветом фона. А когда рисуется цветом фона, то закрашивается

Comment: ОК, используется какой-то неизвестный мне графический модуль. В нём есть пустая кисть? Пустое перо? XOR-режимы или стили пера?

Comment: Думаю,что нет. Видимо, я ошибаюсь
Ну есть инверсия - режим пера

Comment: А, вроде понял. Стиль psSolid

Comment: psSolid - это сплошная, а пустая должна быть psClear

Comment: Описался, да, psClear